# How to handle if post null (nothing) or empty {} for @ResponseBody data

Tags: spring-boot, null

When i create an employee with empty data like {} or null, i get 400 & 500 error. How can i check if the @RequestBody data is empty or null?

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/employee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody(required = false) Employee employee){
        Optional<Employee> emp = employeeService.getEmployeeById(employee.getId());
        if (emp.isPresent()){
            return RestResponse.generateResponse(HttpStatus.FOUND, false, "Employee exist, can't create with id: " + employee.getId(), null);
        }
        employeeService.createEmployee(employee);
        return RestResponse.generateResponse(HttpStatus.CREATED, true, "Employee created with id: " + employee.getId(), employee);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess why you get http 400 or http 500 error is because your @Valid annotation on the other hand if you want to check your RequestBody is null can you can try this ?

```
if(employee == null)
```